# FATAL EXCEPTION: FrescoDecodeExecutor-2

Tags: android, image, fresco

I got the crash FATAL EXCEPTION: FrescoDecodeExecutor-2

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 64256268 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 49MB until OOM"
```

StackTrace :

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 64256268 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 49MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:905)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:882)
                  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:849)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:51)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BitmapPool.alloc(BitmapPool.java:26)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.BasePool.get(BasePool.java:255)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeStaticImageFromStream(ArtDecoder.java:147)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.ArtDecoder.decodeJPEGFromEncodedImage(ArtDecoder.java:127)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decodeJpeg(DefaultImageDecoder.java:173)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder$1.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:56)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.decoder.DefaultImageDecoder.decode(DefaultImageDecoder.java:119)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.doDecode(DecodeProducer.java:254)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder.access$300(DecodeProducer.java:113)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.DecodeProducer$ProgressiveDecoder$1.run(DecodeProducer.java:152)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.doJob(JobScheduler.java:202)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler.access$000(JobScheduler.java:22)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.JobScheduler$1.run(JobScheduler.java:73)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:51)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Image is 5,34 Mo big 5344x3006 and was shoot by the phone Motorola XT1562, Android 7.1.1

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
```

Of course it does not reproduced every time the app is running

What's wrong ? Help ! :-)